# Compare all the properties except few in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

In one of my application, I have a temporary database and want to merge that database to live database. I am using Entity framework for both the database. The entities for both the database are same. I want a logic by which I can compare all the properties except few properties like Id, CreatedOn, etc and if the record doesn't exist then only insert it otherwise skip that record.

I do not want to compare Navigation properties.

Comment: I was thinking the same @EricSondergard

Comment: @manprit: [Give this a read first](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)